# "As long as" or "as long"?

Tags: conjunctions

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

India does not mind mediation as long it puts more pressure on the Pakistanis

At first glance it seemed fine to me. But then shouldn't there be "as long as" instead of "as long"?

Comment: Link to that article- https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.thehindu.com/opinion/op-ed/parley-abhinandans-release-was-a-saving-grace-for-both-sides/article26460448.ece/amp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct there should be an extra **As**. Keep in mind the people writing these articles are sometimes not native speakers of English and therefore they might overlook mistakes like that once in a while, or they might just be native speakers who simply forgot to type in that extra word.

An other alternative for **"as long as"** is **"so long as"** anything different from that is not correct in my opinion.

That would only make sense if it said that the Indians had been minding meditation for too long, and now they're still minding it, but not for as long as before, because it puts pressure on Pakistanis. Which doesn't actually make any sense now that I thought about it again hahahaha.

Answer (score 0):

Of course **as long as**:

> India does not mind mediation **as long as** it puts more pressure on the Pakistanis

It has to be with a **as** ending, since **long it** means no sense, but **long *as* it** does make sense.

This **as long as** would also work if you say: **provided that**.